# How can I resume suspended jobs using powershell using BITS command?

Tags: windows, powershell, microsoft-bits

For BITS Transfer on Windows, There are some JOBIDS whose TransferType is "upload" and JobState is "Suspended". I am executing below command from PowerShell :-

```
Get-BitsTransfer  | Resume-BitsTransfer
```

I am getting below error :-

> Resume-BitsTransfer : Exception from HRESULT: 0x80200003 At line:1
>   char:20
>   + Get-BitsTransfer | Resume-BitsTransfer
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Backg...agement.BitsJob:BitsJob) [Resume-BitsTransfer], COM
>   Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResumeBitsTransferCOMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.Resume
>   BitsTransferCommand

How can I can resume these jobs.

Any Suggestions...

Thanks..... !!

Comment: `0x80200003` is `BG_E_EMPTY`, "The job must contain one or more files before you can resume the job".

Comment: [BITS Return Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362823(v=vs.85).aspx), in addition to Jeroen's helpful comment. Check that `Get-BitsTransfer` successfully returns the jobs you are expecting.